# Is there any configuration to disable key locking for sticky keys?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I like windows default behavior for sticky key.

When I pressed control (`ctrl`, `shift`, ..) key twice, On first click, It hold. On second press, It release lock.

For example: `shift` + `shift` + `a`,`b`,`c` -> `abc`

But on gnome sticky key locked control key, on double click.

For example: `shift` + `shift` + `a`,`b`,`c` -> `ABC`

How to disable this behavior in gnome ?

I don't want to disable 'sticky keys', But only this described behavior.